# Is using Fiat-shamir Heuristic safe?

Tags: hash, zero-knowledge-proofs, data-privacy, schnorr-signature, fiat-shamir

What I'd like to do is to have the *Prover* store a value `x` where `x` remains hidden.

From `x`, I'd like to extract one blob `r1`, and save it in the *Verifier's* database.

Later in the future, the same *Prover* who holds `x` should compute a new `r2` from `x`, such that one cannot easily extract `x` from `r2` and send it over to *Verifier*.

*Verifier* can compare that two distinct and different `r1` and `r2` and know that they came from the same `x` without revealing anything about `x`.

I hope I didn't misunderstand that this is what [Fiat-shamir Heuristic](https://www.math.uni-frankfurt.de/%7Edmst/teaching/SS2012/Vorlesung/Fiat.Shamir.pdf) tried to do.

I made a working example of this based on [this code snippet structure](https://asecuritysite.com/encryption/fiat2):

```
p = Proof()
# k is random
p1.k = random()

# g is a prime number
p1.g = random_prime()

# where r is the commitment of Prover
p1.r = p1.g^p1.k

# Where y is the public key of x
p1.y = p1.g^p1.k

# Where c is the hash of the commitment
p1.c = Hash(p1.r)

# Where s is the output of the commitment algorithm
p1.s = p1.k + p1.c*x

# Now, the Verifier needs to store all of the above somewhere
# After X months, the same Prover makes another blob (call it p2) and wants to verify if p1 came from the same x as p2

(r1, r2) = (p1.g^p1.s * p1.y^p1.c, p2.g^p2.s * p2.y^p1.c)
```

What I'd like to know is the following:

- Is there a known library or codebase that does this somewhere?
- What is a safe bit-size for the prime numbers used (is 4096-bits realistically even possible?)
- Assuming an attacker can sniff `c` and `r` and everything about `p1` and `p2`. How realistically is it that they can A) forge a similar packet and B) extract `x`?

Much appreciated